# Paypal Express Checkout with Intent Authorize not returning authorization id

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

We are using Paypal express checkout which is integrated in our UI project with javascript.
Everything working as expected when we use `intent: sale`.
i.e. `execute` call with `intent: sale` returning `{ sale : {id: ...} }` object for `related_resources` property.
But when I use `intent: authorize` **no** `{ authorization : {id: ...}}` is returning for `related_resources` property. ( it's same behaviour for both paypal, credit_card payment method types).
*Note: I am passing `intent: sale/authorize` for `payment` call*

Comment: Are you using the client-side integration? This is being fixed with the next release

Comment: Yes. I am using Client side integration. By the way, whats the eta for next release?

Comment: We're hoping to release today.

Comment: Thank you @bluepnume. It seems fixed with your new release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been fixed from paypal server api update from their side. Thanks team.